# error message box appearing twice for the same error

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I have series of textboxes in multiple rows. I want to check whether all the textboxes are filled or not in a row before moving to the next row.

I am using the logic as when the focus leaves the last textbox of the row, check if all the textboxes are filled or not.

```
ROW 1 >> txtP1 , txtQ1, txtR1, txtA1
ROW 2 >> txtP2 , txtQ2, txtR2, txtA2 // here txtA1, txtA2 are for decimal inputs

private void txtA2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Decimal amt2;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtA2.Text) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtA2.Text))
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtP2.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtP2.Text)
                   || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtQ2.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtQ2.Text)
                   || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtR2.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtR2.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("please complete the line 2", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    txtP2.Focus();
                    txtA2.Text = "";
                }
                if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtP2.Text) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtP2.Text)) && Decimal.TryParse(txtA2.Text, out amt2))
                {
                    if (amt2 <= 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Amount cannot be zero or negative", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        txtA2.Text = "";
                    }
                    totalAmt += amt2;
                    txtTotal.Text = totalAmt.ToString("#,###.00");
                }
            }
        }
```

When the txtP2, txtQ2, txtR2 are empty and  txtA2 is not empty and I try to move to next row, the message box appears twice.
After the message box appears, the control flows again goes to the line `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtA2.Text) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtA2.Text))` so again the condition is checked and the message box appears again.

Only after that the control flow goes to the second if condition `if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtP2.Text) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtP2.Text)) && Decimal.TryParse(txtA2.Text, out amt2))`.

Please suggest how can I solve this bug.

Comment: The **correct** way to deal with [user input in winforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603(v=vs.110).aspx) is to handle the `Validating` and `Validated` events.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return after displaying the error message:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtP2.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtP2.Text)
   || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtQ2.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtQ2.Text)
   || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtR2.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtR2.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("please complete the line 2", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    txtP2.Focus();
    txtA2.Text = "";
    return;
}
```

or you can use [if else statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx) if you don't want the rest of the checks performed:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtP2.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtP2.Text)
   || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtQ2.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtQ2.Text)
   || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtR2.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtR2.Text))
{
    // ...
}
else if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtP2.Text) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtP2.Text)) && Decimal.TryParse(txtA2.Text, out amt2))
{
    // ...
}
```